# How to get the position of a Key/value pair inside a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash, enumerable

Can the below code can be shortened ?

```
h = { 1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c" }
h.to_a.index([2,'b']) # => 1
```

I didn't find anything in the `Hash` API.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Enumerable#find_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index) as below :

```
h = { 1 => "a", 2 => "b", 3 => "c" }
h.find_index([2,'b']) # => 1
```